# Showing all users not containing a certain value

Tags: sql-server-2005, max, where-clause

I need a way to get a list for all patients who do not have a PCP relation even though patients have multiple relations. The relation also has to be in the current episode. Thanks in advance and I'm running SQL Server 2005

```
select 

distinct r.patient_id, 
r.episode_id, 
r.relation

from 
(select r.*, max(episode_id) over (partition by patient_id) as maxei from relationship r) r
join patient_custom pc
on r.patient_id = pc.patient_id
where health_home = 'y' --and r.relation = 'PCP'
order by r.patient_id, r.relation
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work...  See comments inline.

```
SELECT
    PatientEpisode.Patient_ID,
    PatientEpisode.Epsode_ID

FROM (
    -- Find the list of patients and their current episode
    SELECT r.Patient_ID, MAX(r.Episode_ID) AS Episode_ID
    FROM Relationship r
       JOIN patient_custom pc
       ON r.Patient_ID = pc.Patient_ID
    WHERE pc.Health_Home = 'y'
    GROUP BY r.Patient_ID
) PatientEpisode

-- Now exclude any patients that DO have a "PCP" 
-- relationship in their current episode.
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Relationship
    WHERE Patient_ID = PatientEpisode.Patient_ID
    AND Episode_ID = PatientEpisode.Episode_ID
    AND Relation = 'PCP'
)
```

**EDIT:**
I've added the Health_Home filter.  To understand how this works, first run this `SELECT` by itself:

```
    SELECT r.Patient_ID, MAX(r.Episode_ID) AS Episode_ID
    FROM Relationship r
       JOIN patient_custom pc
       ON r.Patient_ID = pc.Patient_ID
    WHERE pc.Health_Home = 'y'
    GROUP BY r.Patient_ID
```

You'll see that it returns all of the patients as wel as the most recent episode for each patient.

Then once you have that data, it gets wrapped in the rest of the SQL to filter out the patients with current PCP relations.

Comment: This is close, but it needs the health_home = 'y' from the patient_custom table. How would you add that in? This code is a bit above my head. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you. I kinda get it now. I'll work it backwards to get a better grasp. I appreciate the help.

Comment: David not sure if you'll see this, but if you have a chance could you take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540198/couting-combinations-within-a-group