# Couting combinations within a group

Tags: sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, count, group-by

I need a way way to count combinations of code by patients, so I need to know based on this report total duration of each Service Program Protocol, so based on the picture below I need it to be like this

**Patient: 00000036**

Adult CSS IND 240

Adult OP IND 120

**Patient: 00000040**

Adult CSS IND 420

Adult OP IND 60

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and I would prefer a fix in SQL, but if it could be done in crystal I could work with that. Thank you in advance.

```
select 

pct.patient_id,
pct.clinic_id,
pct.service_id,
pct.program_id,
pct.protocol_id,
pct.proc_duration


from patient_clin_tran pct
join patient p
on pct.patient_id = p.patient_id and pct.episode_id = p.episode_id
join patient_custom pc
on pct.patient_id = pc.patient_id
join staff s
on pct.attending_id = s.staff_id
where pc.health_home = 'Y'
group by pct.patient_id, pct.clinic_id, pct.service_id, pct.program_id, pct.protocol_id, pct.proc_duration
order by pct.patient_id, pct.clinic_id, pct.service_id, pct.protocol_id
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  You do need the `GROUP BY`, but you do not want to `GROUP BY` the duration column.  Instead you want to use the `SUM` function in the `SELECT` list on your `proc_duration` column:

```
select 
   pct.patient_id,
   pct.clinic_id,
   pct.service_id,
   pct.program_id,
   pct.protocol_id,
   SUM(pct.proc_duration) AS [Total Duration]  

FROM patient_clin_tran pct
  join patient p
  on pct.patient_id = p.patient_id and pct.episode_id = p.episode_id

  join patient_custom pc
  on pct.patient_id = pc.patient_id

  join staff s
  on pct.attending_id = s.staff_id

where pc.health_home = 'Y'
group by pct.patient_id, pct.clinic_id, pct.service_id, pct.program_id, pct.protocol_id
order by pct.patient_id, pct.clinic_id, pct.service_id, pct.program_id, pct.protocol_id
```

Comment: Thank you David. You are the guru.